# Trying to quicksort a list and return the value to a new variable

Tags: clojure

I am trying to write a program that takes a list of integers and sorts it using either quicksort or mergesort.  I am pretty sure the function is written correctly but when i attempt to print the results, its not sorting.  I am new to clojure so I dont know if im not returning the list correctly or what.

```
(ns mergetime.core)

(use 'clojure.java.io)
(require '[clojure.string :as str])


(defn -main[])

(def string (slurp "100.txt"))
(def numbers (str/split string #"\W+"))
(def nums (mapv #(Integer/parseInt %) numbers))


(defn qsort [L]  
  (if (empty? L)       
    '()      
    (let [[pivot & L2] L]           
      (lazy-cat (qsort (for [y L2 :when (<  y pivot)] y))                     
        (list pivot)                     
        (qsort (for [y L2 :when (>= y pivot)] y))))))


(def nums2 (qsort[nums]))
(println nums2)
```

I except the list to be sorted, however I am just getting an unsorted list

Comment: What's wrong with https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sort ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are wrapping your vector of integers inside another vector.

Try removing the square brackets from your call to `qsort`.

Instead, try this:

```
(def nums2 (qsort nums))
```